# how to trigger a function inside a directives controller when attribute to a directive changes

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-directive

I am trying to call a function inside directives controller as soon as the value to directives attribute changes how do proceed with that thank in advance

Comment: Can you show us some code please? Without any code snippets I would just throw "$watch" on the attribute into the room.

Comment: I want to use this without $watch and controller as syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you have the $attrs :)

```js
$attrs.$observe("myAttr", function(newValue){
  console.log("the attribute my-attr changed to: ", newValue);
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically without $observe similar to the way templates gets updated